# Fréchet derivative of a map from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

Fix a function $f \in L^2(\Bbb R)$.  In fact, let $f$ be continuously differentiable.

Now define a map $\Phi \colon \Bbb R \rightarrow L^2(\Bbb R)$ given by
$$ \Phi(a) = f(a \bullet),$$
meaning the image of $a$ by $\Phi$ is the function 
$$x \mapsto f(ax).$$

I know the Fréchet derivative at $a \in \Bbb R$ is a linear map $A \colon \Bbb R \rightarrow L^2(\Bbb R)$ satisfying
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\Vert f\left(( a + h) \bullet \right) - f(a \bullet) - Ah \Vert_{L^2}}{|h|} = 0,$$
and I had a suspicion that it would be $h \mapsto hf'(h\bullet)$, but the problem is that this map does not seem to be linear, and I am not sure how it would satisfy the above limit.

Can anyone offer some assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative $\Phi'$ is a mapping from $\mathbb R$ to $L^2$ itself, the directional derivative $h\mapsto \Phi'(a)h$ has to be a $L^2$ function.

If $f$ is $C^1$, then the difference quotient $f( (a+h)x-f(ax))/h$ converges pointwise to $f'(ax)x$. Hence if $\Phi$ is Fréchet differentiable, then the directional derivative is given by
$$
(\Phi'(a)h)(x) = f'(ax)hx.
$$ 
This implies that $\int_{\mathbb R} x^2 f'(x)^2 dx<\infty$ is a necessary condition for Fréchet differentiability (and for Gâteaux as well).

If one assumes that $f$ has compact support (and $f(0)=0$ such that $\Phi(0)$ is well-defined) then it should be possible to prove Fréchet differentiability (use dominated convergence theorem).

Comment: Shouldn't the derivative be linear in $h$?  Or is there a difference between directional derivative and Frechet derivative?

Comment: yes, thanks for the comment: see edit, $h$ was missing from that formula